# Python 3.x selenium messenger user picking

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to find the username which I define on Messenger.

So, my logging in is going great.

I want to find this: `<span class="_1ht6">Tetsssss</span>` as

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.messenger.com/t/user.name')

-Some logging in stuff going on here.

usernameToFind = 'Tetssss'
foundUser = driver.findElement(usernameToFind)
```

Of course, if I change the `usernameToFind` variable to another username I want to find the another username.

If you can't find out what I mean because of my not understandable writing please leave a comment.

[Image of what do I want to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUdw7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `user name` you mean, you can use `css selector` with the value: `._1ht6`.

After login you can wait and collect all `user name` use `.visibility_of_all_elements_located`.

First you need following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Try the bellow code:

```
#login
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()

#wait all user name
users = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._1ht6')))

for user in users:
    print(user.text)
```

If you want get only particular user, you can use:

```
print(users[0].text)
```

It will print first `user name`.